# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in soap response parsing in android

Tags: android, ksoap

I get following error when parsing soap responce.

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=3

SOAP response :

```
anyType{ItemId=anyType{}; ItemCode=anyType{}; ItemDescription=10000; UOM=EA; UOMDescription=EA; ItemQty=10000; DelivertoLocId=2005; DelivertoLoc=H1- Retail; }
```

I Used code :

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
for (int i = 0; i < result.getPropertyCount(); i++) 
{ 
     SoapObject obj = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(i);
     Log.d("obj : ", ""+obj);
     Log.d("obj", ""+ obj.getAttribute(3).toString());  // value of column 3
     Log.d("obj1", ""+obj.getProperty(4).toString());  // value of column 4
}
```

Above is proper way for parsing or not ?

Comment: If it fails, I don't think it is the proper way. The SoapObject you are receiving has 0 attributes, so getAttribute(3) throws a out of bounds exception

Answer (score 0):

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
for (int i = 0; i < result.getPropertyCount(); i++) 
{ 
     SoapObject obj = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(i);
     Log.d("obj : ", ""+obj);
     //Log.d("obj", ""+ obj.getAttribute(3).toString());  // value of column 3
     Log.d("obj1", ""+obj.getProperty(4).toString());  // value of column 4
}
```